# Find if a model object is assigned the last instance of another model

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Working on fee management case in Django. Code is given below:

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name",max_length=200)
    cell_no = models.CharField("cell No",max_length=200)
    address = models.CharField("address",max_length=500)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Student"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class FeeType(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("fee Type", max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Fee Type"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class CollectFee(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    feetype = models.ForeignKey(FeeType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amountdue = models.PositiveIntegerField("amount Due")
    amountpaid = models.PositiveIntegerField("amount Paid")
    balance = models.PositiveIntegerField("Balance")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Collect Fee"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.student.name
```

**Fee Type** is like Admission Fee, January Fee, February Fee etc.

I want to get the list of all students who have not yet been assigned the last instance of the FeeType. For example, if in the `CollectFee` the student is assigned January, February month fee then Ok, if the student is not assigned March Fee, he should be included in the list.

I could get the list of all students through:
`students= Student.objects.all()`
I can deal with simple filters but don't know how to apply the filter to solve the above mentioned problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your `FeeType` doesn't have an order, how do you sort it?
Let's add and "`order`" field, even though I dont like to use a SQL-reserved word. Your `CollectFee` model is a "join" between `Student` and `FeeType`. You can use a `ManyToMany` to simplify your life.
Dont forget when you write Python, to separate your words with `_` (= not `feetype` but `fee_type`).

So the code is (*not tested, but should work*):

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField("name",max_length=200)
    collected_fees = models.ManyToMany("FeeType", through="CollectFee")

class FeeType(models.Model):
    order = models.IntegerField(required=True) 
    name = models.CharField("fee Type", max_length=200)

class CollectFee(models.Model):
    student = models.ForeignKey(Student, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    fee_type = models.ForeignKey(FeeType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    amount_due = models.PositiveIntegerField("amount Due")
    amount_paid = models.PositiveIntegerField("amount Paid")
```

---

And some queries (*not tested, but should work*)

---

Get a student, all his fees, and print all the fees he has not yet been assigned:

```
olivier = Student.get(name="Olivier")
for fee in olivier.collected_fees.all():
    print("{fee=}, {fee.amount_due=}, {amount_paid=}")
for fee in FeeType.all().exclude(
    id__in=[f.pk for f in olivier.collected_fees.all()]
):
    print("fee not assigned to {olivier=}: {fee=}")
```

Get last fee (using the field `order`):

```
last_fee = FeeType.all().order_by("order")[-1]
# get all students who doesn't belong to the group of
# "all students who have been assigned the last instance of the FeeType"
for student in Student.all().exclude(pk__in=[
    c_f.student.pk for c_f in CollectFee.filter(
        fee_type=last_fee
    )
]):
    print("Not assigned: {student=}")
```